# Sorting on multiple fields with lst=invariants in Solrconfig

Tags: sorting, solr

I am trying to apply sorting on two different fields named ABC of type date and XYZ of type text in Solr by changing following in Solrconfig file:

```xml
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="invariants">
  <str name="sort">ABC desc</str>
  <str name="sort">XYZ desc</str> 
</lst>
```

I want sorting as per ABC field but if any records have same date that sorting should be as per XYZ field. As per my code I am getting results as per only ABC fields.

Answer (score 1):

In [Solr's reference documentation and there the part about sorting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-ThesortParameter) you can read

> - Multiple sort orderings can be separated by a comma, using this syntax: sort=+,+],...
>
>   - When more than one sort criteria is provided, the second entry will only be used if the first entry results in a tie. If there is a third entry, it will only be used if the first AND second entries are tied. This pattern continues with further entries.

But you have passed two separate parameters for the field, so try to do it as described and separate them with a comma

```xml
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="invariants">
  <str name="sort">ABC desc,XYZ desc</str>
</lst>
```

Comment: But I want the same...if two entries tie up then after sorting should be as per second field. So as per your suggestion my configuration is write. But it doesn't work.

Comment: The way you have written it in your solrconfiguration.xml is syntactically wrong. Solr will only read the first element `<str name="sort">ABC desc</str>` and throw away the second one. You have to write it separated by commas, otherwise it cannot work.